# Create classes from xsd without using xsd.exe

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

I have simple question.
I have xsd file and I have to create classes according to this xsd.

I know I can use xsd.exe from command prompt.
But my solution need to be without xsd (just from c# code).

Is there any framework or known solution for this?

Comment: What you then need to do is receate parts of xsd.exe.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you need. From comments below it seems like you are trying to create a C# program that can build C# classes given an XSD - i.e. your own version of `xsd.exe` - is this correct? (please update your answer to clarify).

Answer (score 0):

Please use  process execution in C# and invoke XSD.exe in that  and provide the schema definitions 
http://www.dotnetperls.com/process

```
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
     // Use Process.Start here.
    Process.Start("C:\\");
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought that is different solution tan execute xsd.exe from code ;)